# python , mantain state used

Tags: python, rest, api, cookies, get

In Python, I want to maintain Cookies and using Cookies want to send GET requests second time ,to fetch JSON data .Why is Set-cookies used .Do I need  to maintain State or cookies

```
import requests
import pprint

url =  'https://shoapi.xxx.com/api/method/login'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'usr':'@gmail.com','pwd':'mh'}
response = requests.request("POST", url,headers=headers,data=payload)
response_data_json = response.json()


print("")
print("")
print(type(response.text))
pprint.pprint(response.text)
print("")
print("")
print("-----------Header---------------")
pprint.pprint(response.headers)
headers=response.headers
print("-----------End of Header---------------------------")
print("")
print("")
print(type(response_data_json))

pprint.pprint(response_data_json)


print("---------------------------")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use requests.Session for the POST, and reuse the same session instance for the subsequent GET requests, the session is maintained, and handles the cookies for you.

```
mysession = requests.Session()
data = {'login': 'mylogin', 'pass': 'mypass'}
mysession.post(myurl, data=data)

mysession.get(myurl2)    #uses logged in session with cookies as set
mysession.get(myurl3)    #reuses session again
```

So you need to maintain state, and not use Set-cookies, unless you really want to handle those things yourself

Comment: The 403 error according to the HTTP specification is "Forbidden".  This probably means one of two things:   Either the URL you are trying to GET is forbidden for a logged in user (test this with a browser), or it is forbidden to user agents such as "python-requests".   If it is forbidden to such user agents, it may be that your script will work if you set the user agent string to be the same as what a browser such as Firefox uses.

Comment: For that user i am able to log in Its not forbidden .  (tested this with a browser), please provide " user agent string" sample code/ Example

Comment: Could it be because the web server you logged in to (shoapi.erpnext.com) is not the same as the one you are trying to GET from (gps.erpnext.com)?

Comment: Can You tel How to create **Session** in **Java Jersey-client** and maintain cookies in java

Comment: Hi, no sorry, I don't know - you're better off asking that as a new question.